# how to Laravel Category - Subcategory

Tags: php, laravel

Hello there I have a new project. I would like to build a multi-category system in this project. 
Example 
Category
 -Subcategory
   -Sub sub category
     -Subsubsubcategory
       -Subsubsubsubcategory
          -Subsubsubcategory.
and so on..

I use laravel 5.4 version. How to make this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a `Category` Model and a table that goes with. In the table add `parent_id`. Now you let's assume you have these categories:

```
Name      id       parent_id
cat1      1        NULL
cat2      2        1
cat3      3        2
cat4      4        3
```

You get it, now `cat4` is a subcategory of `cat3` which is a sub of `cat2` which is a sub of `cat1`.

In the model you can do

```
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id'); get parent category
}

public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id'); //get all subs. NOT RECURSIVE
}
```

Give this a try and see how it goes.

Comment: But in this example, a category cant have more than one parent, how can we etc have shirts for both women, and men ? When building a filter we would have a problem in the structure as the shirts would have 2 rows with different ids

Comment: Same principle. Instead of one to many, do a many to many. A seperate table with parent_id, child_id. Then both relationships become "belongsToMany()".