# Laravel - Display Parent To The Nth Child Values

Tags: laravel

**Please consider the table below**

[image]

**My desired result:**

```
A
---AA1
------AAA1
---------AAAA1
---------AAAA2
---AA2
B
---BB1
---BB2
------BBB1
C
---CC1
------CCC1
---CC2
```

**My problem:**

I need to display on the blade file of this parent to nth-child values. The child is dynamic and can be on any level deep.

I have seen that this should be done using recursive function. I have seen some guide online, but it seem not the one i need.

Can anyone give me a hand here?

**EDIT: Adding my model**

```
class Type extends Model
{
  public function parent()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Type', 'parent_id');
  }

  public function children()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Type', 'parent_id');
  }

  public function childrenRecursive()
  {
    return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive');
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
This is to show the (slightly refactored) final code from the accepted answer, hoping that this may help anyone in the future:

```
public function buildCategoryTreeHtml($types)
    {
      $html = [];

      if($types->count()){
        $html[] = '<ul>';
        foreach($types as $type) {
          $html[] = sprintf(
            '<li>%s%s</li>',
            $type->name,
            $this->buildCategoryTreeHtml($type->children)
          );
        }
        $html[] = '</ul>';
      }
      return implode($html);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Laravel Category - Subcategory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262414/how-to-laravel-category-subcategory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a nested-list of categories in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989728/how-to-create-a-nested-list-of-categories-in-laravel)

Comment: @Mozammil, can you help me on the iteration part on the link you provided?

Comment: The answer explains it very well, but if you show us your models, I could possibly help :)

Comment: @Mozammil - i just added my model on the edit part, thank you in advance!

Comment: `$types = Type::with('childrenRecursive')->where('parent_id', 0)->get();` - this gives me the parent values, but what to do after this? how can iterate this to display up to the nth-child. through foreach loop? what's inside my foreach loop? pls help

Comment: You need to iterate over `$types` until children is null.

Comment: @Mozammil - sir, that's where exactly i am lost at, any hint?

Comment: @kapitan I added my answer. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: @Mozammil - i'll try tomorrow as it's already very late here, thank you very much for your time. i will let you know. salute.

Comment: @kapitan Did you have any luck with it?

Comment: @Mozammil - i edited it due to some syntax error, when it is working, i only got this result: `<ul><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li></ul>` which basically output the parent. any thoughts?

Comment: Oops, missed one `%s`, can you check now?

Comment: whoa! it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually tested it, but I'd have one method to build the HTML for the category tree, for example.

```
public function buildCategoryTreeHtml($categories)
{
    $html = [];

    if(count($categories))
        $html = ['<ul>'];
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $html[] = sprintf(
                '<li>%s %s</li>',
                $category->name,
                $this->buildCategoryTreeHtml($category->children); 
            );
        }
        $html = ['</ul>'];
    }

    return implode($html); 
}
```

You would of course need to pass the categories to it.

```
$categories = Category::with('childrenRecursive')
    ->whereNull('parent')
    ->get();

$html = $this->buildCategoryTreeHtml($categories);
```

That would output the categories in the format you want. Let me know if it works out :)

Comment: it is working perfectly, thank you so much for your time sir mozammil !!!